Is there a way to print strings in quotes, without Debug?
I'm creating a generic error type in Rust, something like:
pub enum MyError<T> {
  DuplicateId<T>,
  // ...
}

Now I need to implement Display for my error type. When T is a string, I would like to quote it. So far whenever I want to quote a string, I just use {:?}, which suggests I should write something like:
impl<T: Debug> Display for MyError<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        match self {
            DuplicateId(id) => write!(f, "duplicate id {:?}")
            // ...
        }
    }
}

But when T is not a string, that's probably not what I want. Instead I probably want to require that the type implements Display and call that.
I guess philosophically, my issue here is that how I think of the Debug/Display distinction ("for inspecting the program's state" vs "for showing the user some text") does not match how I think of the distinction between quoted vs unquoted strings (which is basically the same distinction I make in English, quoted means I'm talking about the words, unquoted means I'm saying them). In my understanding of Debug I would always want strings to be quoted, but in my understanding of Display I might or I might not want it quoted.
Am I missing the point here philosophically at all? Or if not, is there a good solution for this problem?
TBH a mostly harmless workaround would be to use "\"{}\"", only problem is that it gets confusing/ugly if the string contains quotes, and it doesn't handle special characters as I'd like.

How would you like contained double-quotes to be represented?

A possibly-kludgy but maybe-correct way to handle this could be to require T: serde::Serialize and render T as e.g. JSON in the error message, if that interpretation makes sense for most types.

Did you consider https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/struct.TypeId.html?

Can you enumerate all the types you might store in this error type?

str::escape_X() methods are probably what you want. See their docs for differences between them. None of them are exact equivalence to Debug, though, and they always escape Unicode.
If you only want to escape " and \, it's easy to do (not efficiently):
format!("\"{}\"", ss.replace('\\', "\\\\").replace('"', "\\\""))


Yeah at first I thought it's a bit unfortunate that this forces you to quote the Display result of any T and not just strings. However, I'm not sure that is actually a coherent argument given the philosophical position I put out in my question. So yeah I guess just quoting explicitly is the way to go!
